# sort rows in datagrid in reverse order

Tags: asp.net

Sir, I am using a data grid to show the content of a table that contains three columns, namely, senderID(varchar), message(varchar), recieverID(varchar).I am displaying these in a datagrid. I want to display the rows in reverse order in data grid, i.e., the row1 in table should be last in the datagrid while the last row in the table should be first in datagrid. I cannot use orderby clause because there is no column which i can use to sort. any help would be appreciated

Comment: ya but i only want the "msg" column to be there in the data grid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your query sent to the SQL server ?

You should be able to do an ORDER BY col DESC for every column in the aggregated join !

Comment: its like,
select msg from messages where recieverID=session["currentusername"].ToString()

Comment: helllppppppppppppppppppppppppppp!